# How to apologize for not having followed a conversation

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose at some point during a meeting or even a casual conversation your mind wandered off and you stopped listening. Then suddenly someone asks you a question. You want to let them know you've been thinking about something else for a moment and haven't been following, really.

I would say something like "sorry, I was/got lost in thought" but it seems too formal and even awkward.

What are the options (and is the one proposed above valid)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the question of politeness aside, there are a number of idiomatic ways to describe this kind of lapse of attention.

Sorry, ...

I was daydreaming.

My mind was wandering.

I was thinking about {something else}

I was going over in my mind ...

I must have drifted off there ... (sleepiness)

I missed what was said there. It just dawned on me that ... (e.g. I forgot to turn off the oven)

"I was lost in thought" is valid.

Answer (score 0):

*What's that?* (a very British locution in this context)

*What..**what**?* (a very American one...)

*Um, come again?*

*I am not sure I got your point.* (Slyly implying that you were listening, but they did not express themselves clearly.)

*So yeah, sure, I guess... you were saying?*